# Button on ng-mouseover & ng-mouseleave won't get shown as expected - AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I've a problem that I wasn't able to solve for a while now, even looking to other Q/A on SO.

I would like to switch from a button to another one with an `ng-show`.

- When `ng-mouseover`triggers, I would like to hide the current button, `button-db`, and show a second one, `button-shout`
- When `ng-mouseleave` triggers, I would like to do the opposite, hiding `button-shout` and showing `button-db`.

I'm already able to make this work with the following code:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="footer">
  <div ng-show="hoverEdit" class="half button-db" 
       ng-mouseover="hoverIn()" ng-mouseleave="hoverOut()">
          <span class="shout-value">200</span>       
  </div>
  <div ng-show="!hoverEdit" class="half button-shout" 
       ng-mouseover="hoverIn()" ng-mouseleave="hoverOut()">
     <div class="icon-over" ng-src="./assets/css/img/logo-white-m.png" 
          style="width: 29px; height: 21px;"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="half button-action">
   <span class="icon-cart" ng-src="./assets/css/img/icon-cart.png" 
         style="width: 29px; height: 21px;"></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
$scope.hoverEdit = true;

$scope.hoverIn = function(){
    $scope.hoverEdit = false;
};

$scope.hoverOut = function(){
    $scope.hoverEdit = true;
};
```

With the code above I'm able to get the following starter situation:

[image: button-db on the left and button-action on the right]

> `button-db` on the left and `button-action` on the right

And I would like that, when `ng-mouseover` triggers, `button-db` (The Purple Rectangle) gets hidden while `button-shout` (~Green Rectangle with another image) gets shown and vice-versa (this is actually working), like in the following image:

[image: what I'm trying to achieve -> button-shout on the left at button-db's place]

> What I'm trying to achieve -> `button-shout` on the left at `button-db`'s place

But, instead, I get the following result:

[image: what I get instead]

> What I get instead, when I go over `button-db` I get this uknown blank div instead of `button-shout`

`button-shout` doesn't get shown and it is not present in the DOM and it does not have `height` and `width` even if I managed to build it like I did with the other buttons.

I'm using the following **CSS** classes:

**half** gives dimensions to the buttons and sets their position

```
.pod .footer .half {
  display: table-cell;
  padding-top: 1px;
  padding-left: 8px;
  padding-right: 8px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  height: 45px;
}
```

**button-db** has both `:before` and `:after` with a little images and `shout-value` to handle the `int number` between them

```
.pod .footer .button-db {
  background-color: #6ab5ac;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #6455a0;
}
.pod .footer .button-db .shout-value {
  margin-top: 0px;
  padding: 2px;
  color: #fff;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 600;
  line-height: 22px;
}
.pod .footer .button-db .shout-value:before {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  background-image: url("./assets/css/img/shout-megaphone-white.svg");
  background-size: contain;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 30px;
  height: 23px;
  position: absolute;
  left: -17px;
  top: 0px;
}
.pod .footer .button-db .shout-value:after {
  content: "";
  background-image: url("./assets/css/img/shout-db-white.svg");
  background-size: contain;
  background-position: right center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 28px;
  height: 27px;
  position: absolute;
  right: -19px;
  top: -1px;
  vertical-align: super;
  font-size: 12px;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0;
  padding-top: 0px;
  font-weight: 500;
}
.pod .footer .button-db .shout-value .db {
  vertical-align: super;
  font-size: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0;
}
.pod .footer .button-db .db-value {
  margin-top: 0px;
  padding: 2px;
  color: #fff;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 600;
  line-height: 22px;
}
.pod .footer .button-db .db-value:after {
  content: "dB";
  background-image: none;
  width: 28px;
  height: 23px;
  position: absolute;
  right: -19px;
  top: 0px;
  vertical-align: super;
  font-size: 12px;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0;
  padding-top: 0px;
  font-weight: 500;
}
```

**button-shout** button to get shown when `ng-mouseover` triggers; It does not need any `:before` and `:after`, it only has 1 image and no values

```
.pod .footer .button-shout {
  background-color: #6AB6AC;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: #fff;
  line-height: 30px;
}
```

**button-action** cart button, `button-shout` would look pretty much like it but for the color and the image

```
.pod .footer .button-action {
  background-color: #ffae00;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: #fff;
  line-height: 30px;
}
```

The functionalities I implemented using both `ng-mouseover` and `ng-mouseleave` work perfectly as I want. I don't get why `button-shout` has no dimensions and does not get shown at `button-db`'s place when doing `ng-mouseover`.

I already tried using `ng-if`, adding and removing classes, using `z-index` and `display: none` & `display: block` but I always get this problem.

I noticed that `button-shout` inherits nothing except for `half`'s placement.

[Here is a little Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/e2ZEyaUy0bldV6f3OzVH) I put up with only two buttons to let you understand how it should work. It works on the Plunker but not in my application.

When `mouseover` triggers, one button hides and the other one is shown and when `mouseleave` triggers, the old one is shown back.

**1) Have you any idea on why it doesn't get shown properly?**

**2) How can I fix this?**

I hope I've been as much clear as possible, Thanks in advance.

Comment: instead of doing it this way, you can just change the image path remember you are using ng-src, you can do this ng-src={{myPath}} .. and then on mouseenter/mouseleave update $scope.myPath

Comment: I already tried that and I always get the same result.

Comment: it's the best way to do this, but if you insist ... I'm confused by this <div class="icon-over" ng-src="./assets/css/img/logo-white-m.png" 
          style="width: 29px; height: 21px;"></div>

Comment: what is this logo /logo-white-m.png ??

Comment: ng-src should be in an IMG tag

Comment: The logo that I want to get shown in the green button as in the screenshot above.

Comment: Why don't you use <i> for the icon

Comment: are you sure hoverEdit has the right value you want ?

Comment: Already tried that but nothing changes.

Comment: `hoverEdit` works as expected. I only get that white Rectangle instead of the wanted one.

Comment: Then when you mouse-leave the white rectangle do you see the first button ?

Comment: did you try ng-if instead of ng-show ?

Comment: Yes, I tried that also and nothing changes.

Comment: Could you provide an issue demonstrating the problem?

Comment: Is second button rendered correct if you remove `ng-show` from it?

Comment: @Aides Do you mean a Plunker? @Vp-Arth No, it does not get rendered. I tried hiding `button-db` and showing `button-shout` by default but I get the same result.

Comment: Yeah, just any kind of MCVE

Comment: A plunker would help a lot on this, but from a quick look I can tell you a mouseover event attached to an element which is supposed to disappear is a big nay-nay :) (ps: Might not be your actual solution for the problem without seeing a plunker in action) - Also as Mayk pointed... why you have a ng-src attribute on a div tag? Isn't that supposed to be an img tag or are you doing something else with it on your controller (which I would absolutely avoid) ?

Comment: The project is huge and would be difficult for me to set up a complete Plunker, but here's a partial one: https://plnkr.co/edit/e2ZEyaUy0bldV6f3OzVH . It would be cool also if it works on that little example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To be honest i'm not really sure of what the problem is so i'll post here a snippet that try to reproduce what you currently have. Feel free to tell us if this snippet reproduces your problem and for answeres to use it as a base for an answer.

Note : in your HTML i removed the ng-mouseleave on 1st element and ng-mouseenter on 2nd because they were conflicting each other and throw duplicate events.

```js
angular.module("app", []).controller("ctrl", ['$scope', function($scope){
    $scope.hoverEdit = true;

$scope.hoverIn = function(){
    console.log("HOVER IN");
    $scope.hoverEdit = false;
};

$scope.hoverOut = function(){
    $scope.hoverEdit = true;
      console.log("HOVER OUT");
};
}]);
```

```css
.pod .footer .half {
  display: table-cell;
  padding-top: 1px;
  padding-left: 8px;
  padding-right: 8px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  height: 45px;
}



.pod .footer .button-db {
  background-color: #6ab5ac;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #6455a0;
}
.pod .footer .button-db .shout-value {
  margin-top: 0px;
  padding: 2px;
  color: #fff;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 600;
  line-height: 22px;
}
.pod .footer .button-db .shout-value:before {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: black;/*url("./assets/css/img/shout-megaphone-white.svg");*/
  background-size: contain;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 30px;
  height: 23px;
  position: absolute;
  left: -17px;
  top: 0px;
}
.pod .footer .button-db .shout-value:after {
  content: "";
  background-image: white;/*url("./assets/css/img/shout-db-white.svg");*/
  background-size: contain;
  background-position: right center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 28px;
  height: 27px;
  position: absolute;
  right: -19px;
  top: -1px;
  vertical-align: super;
  font-size: 12px;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0;
  padding-top: 0px;
  font-weight: 500;
}
.pod .footer .button-db .shout-value .db {
  vertical-align: super;
  font-size: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0;
}
.pod .footer .button-db .db-value {
  margin-top: 0px;
  padding: 2px;
  color: #fff;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 600;
  line-height: 22px;
}
.pod .footer .button-db .db-value:after {
  content: "dB";
  background-image: none;
  width: 28px;
  height: 23px;
  position: absolute;
  right: -19px;
  top: 0px;
  vertical-align: super;
  font-size: 12px;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0;
  padding-top: 0px;
  font-weight: 500;
}


.pod .footer .button-shout {
  background-color: #6AB6AC;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: #fff;
  line-height: 30px;
}

.pod .footer .button-action {
  background-color: #ffae00;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: #fff;
  line-height: 30px;
}
```

```html
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<div class="pod">
<div class="footer" ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <div ng-show="hoverEdit" class="half button-db" 
       ng-mouseover="hoverIn()">
          <button class="shout-value">100</button>       
  </div>
  <div ng-show="!hoverEdit" class="half button-shout" 
      ng-mouseleave="hoverOut()">
         <button class="shout-value">200</button>
  </div>

  <div class="half button-action">
     <button class="shout-value">300</button>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Of course since i don't have the images, i changed them to black and white background. What i can see is that i have a black crap that seems to not be in the right place, however this doesn't seems to be what your problem is.

Answer (score 1):

Check if mouseover trigger the function or not. Mouseover should change value on ng-show value from false to true in your html.

Comment: Mouseover and Mouseleave already work as i want them to do. The problem is binded to button-shout class only. It doesn't get shown.

Comment: What do you see when you inspect the element?  Does your divorce have the corresponding class?

Comment: yes it does whenever an event happen . you need to check even got fired and corresponding value changes in html for class and ng-show atribute. sometime event Propagation fires two events at same time.

Answer (score 1):

I may be mis-reading, but why are any functions needed here? If you are just trying to toggle a class, how about this? it will not require any controller functions.

https://plnkr.co/edit/HMACVKTlLzbkfWhy4v1S?p=preview

```
<div class="half"
      ng-init="hover = false"
      ng-class="hover ? 'button-shout' : 'button-db'"
      ng-mouseenter="hover = true"
      ng-mouseleave="hover = false">

<div class="icon-over">300</div>
```